# How to use Spring messages in EJS template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ejs

I consider moving from Thymeleaf templating to EJS templating in my Spring Boot application (there is a need to execute some javascript code on server side). I've successfully configured everything and created my first view using few online examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello <%= username %>
</body>
</html>
```

This works OK when I pass String variable named "username" from controller to view. However, I would like my view to use messages from static file "/resources/i18n/messages.properties". In thymeleaf it is widely used, simple and possible by:

```
th:text="#{messages.hellomessage}"
```

How to achieve the same result using EJS?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new [ScriptTemplateViewResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/script/ScriptTemplateViewResolver.html) and also create a new [ScriptTemplateConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/script/ScriptTemplateConfigurer.html) leveraging the `Nashorn` support as engine.

[Take a look at this tutorial for an example](https://patrickgrimard.io/2016/11/24/server-side-rendering-with-spring-boot-and-react/).

Comment: How is that answering my question? My problem is using static "messages.properties" file in ".ejs" template or ".js" script like it is possible in jsp (https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/) or thymeleaf (https://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/). Hovewer, thanks for the tutorial, I'll try to ask its author.